# PHP Loop array object once, or wild card key?

Tags: php, loops

I have a php array, and inside the array is a reference to another php object with a numerical value.

How can i access the elements in this array without knowing that numerical id (it could be different for each array)?

In the image below, I need to get the values inside field_collection_item like so....

```
$content['field_image_columns'][0]['entity']['field_collection_item'][133]['field_image']
```

For the first array key (0) i have done the following...

```
$i = 0; 
    while($i <= 2) {
        if(isset($content['field_image_columns'][$i])) {
            print '<div class="column-' . $i . '">';

            foreach ($content['field_image_columns'][$i]['entity']['field_collection_item'] as $fcid => $values) {
                // Print field values
            }

            print '</div>';
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

Doing a foreach loop for a single array item seems wrong - is there a method i should be using for this use case?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select first item of array for example with:

1. Use `array_shift`, but it will **modify** source array:

   ```
   $cur = array_shift($content['field_image_columns'][$i]['entity']['field_collection_item']);
   print $cur['field_image'];
   ```
2. Get keys of array with `array_keys` and use first element of result as a key

   ```
   $ks = array_keys($content['field_image_columns'][$i]['entity']['field_collection_item']);
   print $content['field_image_columns'][$i]['entity']['field_collection_item'][$ks[0]]['field_image'];
   ```
3. Use `current` function:

   ```
   $cur = current($content['field_image_columns'][$i]['entity']['field_collection_item']);
   print $cur['field_image'];
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As with most programming, there are quite a few ways you could do it.  If a foreach works, then it isn't wrong, but it may not be the best way.

```
// Get the current key from an array
$key = key($array);
```

If you don't need the key, then you can just get the value from the array.

```
// Get the current value from an array
$value = current($array);
```

Both of these will retrieve the first key/value from the array assuming you haven't advanced the pointer.

current, key, end, reset, next, & prev are all array functions that allow you to manipulate an array without knowing anything about the internals.  http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: Awesome! That makes sense! Thank you :-)